# How to stop/start a subscription in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my app i have two forms. Each one is shown to the user based on a select dropdown value.

```
    <select (change)="change($event)">
            <option value="0">New</option>
            <option value="1">Existing</option>
    </select>
```

Then in .ts file:

```
     ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.existingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(p => {
        //code
        });
        this.newForm.valueChanges.subscribe(p => {
        //code
        });
     }

     change($event) {
       if ($event.target.value == 0) {
         //pause newForm subscription
         //start existing subscription
       }
       if ($event.target.value == 1) {
         //pause existing subscription
         //start newform subscription
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

invoke `subscribe()` to an `Observable` will start `subscribe`. 
and keep the subscription by `let subscription = this.existingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(...)` to stop subscribe by `subscription.unsubscribe()`.

---

- keep the observerble

  let observable$ = this.existingForm.valueChanges;
- start or restart

  let subscription = observable$.subscribe();
- stop

  subscription.unsubscribe();

Comment: i was checking the subscription api, but i don have the 'subscribe' method to 'start' it again.

Comment: @ggui you can keep the Observable in order to restart subscribe to it again. see my updated answer.